# How to provide updates for client's mysql database without loosing clients existing data?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I am working on the project like wordpress. Where clients will be notified when updates are available. I am done with providing UI updates but how to provide database updates. What steps should i follow?

Database updates may include

- Creation of new tables or
- Deletion / Updation of new tables.

Then how can I update client database without affecting his/her existing data?

Please help.

Comment: Can't answer this without knowing the current structure and proposed changes. Usually you can change database structures without losing data though.

Comment: @GordonM agree with you, but then how wordpress would be managing database changes and provide database updates? Please let me know if any soln. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: To me your question is a little vague. Wordpress manages database changes and updates the same as anybody else, with well crafted SQL statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for *database migration*. The general idea is that you should provide a script to downgrade and upgrade your database between different versions.

- http://davedevelopment.co.uk/2008/04/14/how-to-simple-database-migrations-with-phing-and-dbdeploy.html
- http://drarok.com/ladder/